# Bash expr command

Tags: bash, expr, parameter-expansion

I am trying to make a bash shell script that can add a name value pair to a text file, for example `TEST=true`. I am trying to make it so if the user tries to add a name that already exists for example `TEST=false` it does not let them to do it.  Can anyone tell me how to use the `expr` command to extract any text before the `=` character? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`expr` is an external command. you can just use bash to do it

```
s="TEST=true"
echo ${s%%=*}


OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS="="
set -- $s
echo $1
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need?

if [[ $input =~ (.?*)= ]]

then

```
    echo $BASH_REMATCH is what I wanted    

    echo but just ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

fi

http://aplawrence.com/Linux/bash-regex.html